# Inserting Multiple rows in Mysql table with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, record

I am in a fix here. I have code that does not insert multiple data into mysql table with one form. Here's my code-

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submitted'])) {
  include('config.php');
  foreach($_POST['name'] as $row=>$nam) {
    $name=$nam;
    $class=$_POST['class'][$row];
    echo "<br/>" . $name . "<br/>" . $class;
    $sql="INSERT INTO multiple (name, class) VALUES ('$name','$class')";
  }
  if (!mysql_query($sql)) die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
  echo "1 record added";
}
?>

<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
<label>Name1:
<input id="name" name="name[]" type="text">
<input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="true" />
</label>
<label> Class1:
<input id="class" name="class[]" type="text">
</label>
<label>Name2:
<input id="name" name="name[]" type="text">
</label>
<label>Class2:
<input id="class" name="class[]" type="text">
</label>
<label>Name3:
<input id="name" name="name[]" type="text">
</label>
<label>Class3:
<input id="class" name="class[]" type="text">
</label>
<label>Name4:
<input id="name" name="name[]" type="text">
</label>
<label>Class4:
<input id="class" name="class[]" type="text">
</label>
<label>Name5:
<input id="name" name="name[]" type="text">
</label>
<label>Class5:
<input id="class" name="class[]" type="text">
</label>
<input value="Add" type="submit">

</form>
```

When I press the submit button nothing inserts in the mysql table. Only empty fields are created. If I insert 5 text field I get 5 empty fields in sql table.

Comment: `mysql_*` is deprecated, and your code is open to SQL injection.

Comment: please show us the output of your echo statement.  also echo $sql;

Comment: It's illegal to duplicate `id`'s the way you are doing. Each value in `id=""` must only be used once.

Comment: Please show us the output of `print_r($_POST);` then we can debug this. Put that right at the top of the form.

Comment: 1 record addedArray ( [name] => Array ( [0] => Arti [1] => [2] => [3] => [4] => ) [submitted] => true [class] => Array ( [0] => a [1] => [2] => [3] => [4] => ) )  this is shown while print_r($_POST); Here "Arti" is a Name and "a" is a class

Comment: @Ariel id=""; should be used only once? that means, I will have only one id for each textbox? am I getting it right? sorry bro, I am amateur in PHP. still need a lot to learn!

Comment: @Ariel id's have nothing to do with posting, less your posting with ajax and using the ID's as your selectors in javascript, then and only then they might be a bother (but a little scripting to handle that as well can fix it). Now as far as html compliance per the W3C or RFC or whatever, then yes, thats deemed as illegal as far as markup goes.

Comment: @chris I know that, that's why I posted it as two separate comments.

Comment: IDs should only be used once.  If you're giving them the same name use classes instead.  But that shouldn't be making a difference.  You also don't need the hidden input, since you can just give the submit button a `name` and check the `$_POST` array if that input is submitted.  I'd also recommend switching to PDO or mysqli since mysql is deprecated.  And use a function like `mysqli_real_escape_string` to prevent SQL injection.

Comment: @ImrozAhmad Correct, each textbox needs it's own `id` - but really, I wouldn't bother giving them `id`'s at all unless I actually need those `id`'s and in this app you don't.

Comment: Thanks Ariel. I got your point.

Comment: @AlexKalicki Can you help me with a PDO or mysqli? cause these are new for me! I am so amateur in PHP!

Comment: In your case you don't have much to change - just use the [`mysqli_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) function instead of `mysql_query`.  And wrap your `$name` and `$class` variable assignments with a [`mysqli_real_escape_string`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) function.

Answer (score 1):

Imroz, your use of `[]` as part of the names of your input elements (not id's) example `name="class[]"` when the form is posted it builds an array. The post object PHP would recognize would be `$_POST['class']`

But that being an array means you have to handle it slightly different before inserting it into your database as you can't just (well maybe you can) drop an array into the DB

if you did

```
for($x=0;$x < count($_POST['class']); $x++)
{
    echo $_POST['class'][$x].'<br>';
}
```

you would be able to see all your posted inputs from the inputs with the name `class[]`

of course this is a core example of what you need to do overall, but I am just trying to express whats going on with your posted data.

Comment: The OP's already taking into account that these are arrays using a foreach loop to iterate through.

Comment: Thank You Chris. I understand now, why empty fields are inserted. Thanks a lot Chris!

Comment: Chris, in the system you showed, is still inserting empty rows in the table :(

Answer (score 1):

i think your inserting query is problem.....try like this

```
$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO category VALUES('','$name','$class','')") or die(mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the `}` in the wrong place.

The `}` right after the `$sql=` should be moved after the `echo "1 record added";`

I reformatting your code to use proper indenting and the error was obvious.